# Benchmark experiment using MLR: No correlation coefficients for LASSO (but for SVR and Random Forest)

Tags: r, benchmarking, correlation, lasso-regression, mlr

I conducted a benchmark experiment using the `mlr` package in R. Among others I chose three correlation coefficients as my performance measures (`spearmanrho`, `my.pearson`, `kendalltau`). I am benchmarking the following learner: LASSO (`regr.cvglmnet`), Suppport Vector Regression (`regr.ksvm`), and Random Forest (`regr.ranger`).

However, I am only getting results for SVR and Random Forest. For LASSO it returns NA for all three correlation performance measure.

Question: Does anyone know, why?

On another note, it would only make sense to report Pearson for LASSO (as it is the only linear model) and for the other two either kendalltau or spearmanrho, right?

I would highly appreciate a response.

Code:

```
set.seed(1)

df <- data.frame(ID=c(1:100),
                 x= sample(1:100),
                 y= sample(1:100))

install.packages("mlr")
install.packages("glmnet") #package for LASSO
install.packages("kernlab") #package for SVR
install.packages("ranger") #package for rf
Packages <- c("mlr", "glmnet", "e1071", "ranger")
lapply(Packages, library, character.only = TRUE) 

###Step 1) Computing the tasks 
regr.task_df = makeRegrTask(id = "test", data = df, target = "x")

###Step 2) Tuning via inner resampling loop (for each algorithm)

##LASSO

lrn_LASSO = makeLearner("regr.cvglmnet") 
parsLASSO =  makeParamSet(
  makeDiscreteParam("s", values = c("lambda.1se", "lambda.min"))
) 

tuneLASSO = makeTuneControlRandom() 
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2) 
learnerLASSO = makeTuneWrapper(lrn_LASSO, resampling = inner, par.set = parsLASSO, control = tuneLASSO, show.info = FALSE) #do I need/ want to specify measure here (e.g. , measures = spearmanrho or mse) 

##SVR

lrn_SVR = makeLearner("regr.ksvm") 

parsSVM = makeParamSet(
  makeNumericParam("C", lower = -10, upper = 10, trafo = function(x)2^x),  
  makeNumericParam("sigma", lower = -10, upper = 10, trafo = function(x)2^x)
) 

tuneSVM = makeTuneControlRandom() 
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2)

learnerSVM = makeTuneWrapper(lrn_SVR, resampling = inner, par.set = parsSVM, control = tuneSVM, show.info = FALSE)

##Random Forest

lrn_RF = makeLearner("regr.ranger", par.vals = list("num.trees" = 10L)) 

parsRF = makeParamSet(
  makeIntegerParam("min.node.size" , lower = 1, upper = 12)
)

tuneRF = makeTuneControlRandom() 
inner = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2) 

learnerRF = makeTuneWrapper(lrn_RF, resampling = inner, par.set = parsRF, control = tuneRF, show.info = FALSE)

###Step 3) Benchmarking via outer resampling loop

#Learners to be compared
lrns = list(
  makeLearner("regr.featureless"), #creating one without any features as a baseline
  learnerLASSO,
  learnerSVM,
  learnerRF
)

#outer resampling strategy
rdesc = makeResampleDesc("CV", iters = 2) 

#define measures 

meas <- list(mse, mae, rmse, rsq, kendalltau, spearmanrho, my.pearson) 

#benchmark
df_benchmarking <- benchmark(learners = lrns, 
                                 tasks = regr.task_df, 
                                 resamplings = rdesc, 
                                 models = FALSE, #to not keep the fitted models for all learners on all tasks to save memory (fitted models can be retrieved by function getBMRModels)
                                 measures = meas)
```

Output:

```
Task: test, Learner: regr.featureless
Resampling: cross-validation
Measures:             mse           mae           rmse          rsq           kendalltau    spearmanrho   pearsonsr     
[Resample] iter 1:    823.0228000   25.2896000    28.6883740    -0.0075292          NA            NA            NA      
[Resample] iter 2:    852.7028000   24.8392000    29.2010753    -0.0072652          NA            NA            NA      


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=837.8628000,mae.test.mean=25.0644000,rmse.test.rmse=28.9458598,rsq.test.mean=-0.0073972,kendalltau.test.mean=      NA,spearmanrho.test.mean=      NA,pearsonsr.test.mean=      NA


Task: test, Learner: regr.cvglmnet.tuned
Resampling: cross-validation
Measures:             mse           mae           rmse          rsq           kendalltau    spearmanrho   pearsonsr     
[Resample] iter 1:    823.0228000   25.2896000    28.6883740    -0.0075292          NA            NA            NA      
[Resample] iter 2:    852.7028000   24.8392000    29.2010753    -0.0072652          NA            NA            NA      


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=837.8628000,mae.test.mean=25.0644000,rmse.test.rmse=28.9458598,rsq.test.mean=-0.0073972,kendalltau.test.mean=      NA,spearmanrho.test.mean=      NA,pearsonsr.test.mean=      NA


Task: test, Learner: regr.ksvm.tuned
Resampling: cross-validation
Measures:             mse           mae           rmse          rsq           kendalltau    spearmanrho   pearsonsr     
[Resample] iter 1:    814.0693912   25.1901372    28.5319013    0.0034314     0.2284100     0.2911033     0.2326230     
[Resample] iter 2:    780.3428232   23.3046787    27.9346169    0.0782108     0.1493878     0.2074910     0.3015794     


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=797.2061072,mae.test.mean=24.2474079,rmse.test.rmse=28.2348385,rsq.test.mean=0.0408211,kendalltau.test.mean=0.1888989,spearmanrho.test.mean=0.2492971,pearsonsr.test.mean=0.2671012


Task: test, Learner: regr.ranger.tuned
Resampling: cross-validation
Measures:             mse           mae           rmse          rsq           kendalltau    spearmanrho   pearsonsr     
[Resample] iter 1:    763.1294514   23.3170000    27.6247978    0.0657911     0.2206785     0.3080654     0.3227492     
[Resample] iter 2:    844.0942578   24.5514734    29.0533003    0.0029037     0.0875616     0.1308357     0.1717654     


Aggregated Result: mse.test.mean=803.6118546,mae.test.mean=23.9342367,rmse.test.rmse=28.3480485,rsq.test.mean=0.0343474,kendalltau.test.mean=0.1541201,spearmanrho.test.mean=0.2194506,pearsonsr.test.mean=0.2472573


There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)
>
```

Comment: Can you post a complete example that allows to reproduce the problem please?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I included a dummy data set and the code, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks. Typing `warnings()` at the end reveals the source of the NAs -- the standard deviation is 0.